# Why does malloc keep giving a "incompatible types" error when assigning memory even though both the pointer and the typecasting are of correct type

Tags: c, list, struct, declaration, singly-linked-list

```
void createLL(int A[], struct Node *a)
{
    struct Node* b, temp;

     a->data = A[0];
     a->next = NULL;
     b=a;

     for(int i=1;i < SIZE;i++)
     {
         temp = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
         temp->data = A[i];
         temp->next = NULL;
         b->next = temp;
         b =temp;
     }
}
```

Error:

```
1.37.0\LinlL.c:19:10: error: incompatible types when assigning to type 'struct Node' from type 'struct Node *'
temp = (struct Node *)malloc(sizeof(struct Node)); 
^
```

Comment: Please do not make up the code you show us. Show us the real messages and code. The error message does not match the code you show us. In the code you cast to `(struct Node*)` while the error messages shows `(struct Node)`

Comment: @Gerhardh I have copy-pasted directly from the IDE. The only reason I thought it wasn't my mistake, to begin with, was because of the misleading error message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
struct Node* b, temp;
```

should be

```
struct Node *b, *temp;
```

In the first version, `temp` is a `struct Node`; i.e. not a pointer type so the compiler issues a diagnostic when you attempt to assign a pointer type to it.

It's fashionable to think of the pointer as part of the type in a declaration rather than the variable, but that's not really the case. With a single variable declaration it makes no difference, but does so with more than one, as is the case here.

Also, casting the result of `malloc` in C is not necessary (it is in C++), and is even occasionally harmful.

Comment: It's even worse. In the error message it can be seen that the cast in the real code was `(struct Node )` instead of a pointer type.

Comment: Ah yes, the good old "casting malloc's return value to completely discard any useful warning".

Answer (score 1):

There is a typo in this declaration

```
struct Node* b, temp;
```

It means in fact the following declarations

```
struct Node* b;
struct Node temp;
```

That is the variable `b` is declared as a pointer while the variable `temp` is declared as an object of the structure type.

You have to write

```
struct Node *b, *temp;
```

The reason of the typo is that you declared the variable `temp` in the scope where it is not used. You should declare it within the for loop.:)

In any case **the function is invalid** because the original node (I think the head of the list) is passed to the function by value. That is the function deals with a copy of the head node. Any changes of the copy that is of the variable `a` do not influence on the value of the original node head.

The function can be defined the following way.

```
void createLL( const int A[], struct Node **a)
{
     for ( int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++ )
     {
         *a = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
         ( *a )->data = A[i];
         ( *a )->next = NULL;
         a = &( *a )->next;
     }
}
```

and called like

```
struct Node *head = NULL;
int A[SIZE] = { /* some values */ };

// ...

createLL( A, &head );
```

Comment: I really really dislike `struct Node* b, *temp;`. Do you use that in production code?